# Python; Error with Pandas to_excel() function, Permission Error [win32]

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I'm reading from an excel (.xlsx) file using pandas `read_excel()` and trying to write back to the same file using pandas `to_excel()` function. For some reason with small files (20-30 rows) it works fine but when I put in a larger file (200,000 rows) it gives me a permission error.

```
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'C:\\Users\\...\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\1\\openpyxl._fbk93l5'
```

I'm assuming the reader somehow still has its hands on the file when it attempts to overwrite back to it but I'm not sure how to resolve this. I make sure to close the file from excel before running the program.

edit:

these are my read and write functions

```py
    def readData(excelFilePath):
        print("Reading data...\n")
        data = pd.read_excel(excelFilePath)
        return data

    def writeData(data, excelFilePath):
        data.to_excel(excelFilePath, index=False)
        print("\nData Updated...\nProgram exiting...")
        sleep(2)
```

I read the data, manipulate it then write back to the same file

Any help is appreciated,
Thanks

Comment: Could you edit your question to include your code?

Comment: @RachayitaGiri edited with my read and write functions

Comment: What happens if you try to write to a new file? Could you then just rename the file as the original or is it still saying it's open?

Comment: Change the file path that you are using to the absolute file path, like `C:/.../yourpath`.

Comment: @MattR unfortunately no, even more strange in this case since its not even writing back to the original file yet still says the exact same error

Comment: Are you closing your writer/filehandle after reading, and before you start writing?

Comment: @RachayitaGiri the variable `excelFilePath` is already the absolute path

Comment: @RachayitaGiri i couldn't find a close function for pandas `read_excel()` function. Does such a thing exist?

Comment: I am sorry, I was under the impression that you are using the `ExcelWriter`. But if you are not, I think it is a good idea to. Look at the code in this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45479110/permission-error-when-pandas-dataframe-is-write-to-xlsx-file/45479651. This will let you open or close the writer.

Comment: @RachayitaGiri i need to close the reader not the writer